# So I'm trying to make an app using PyQt5. Tried to give some functionality to a button, throws an error

Tags: python-3.x, file, pyqt, file-browser

```
def openFileNameDialog(self):
        options = QFileDialog.Options()
        options |= QFileDialog.DontUseNativeDialog
        fileName, _ = QFileDialog.getOpenFileName(self,"QFileDialog.getOpenFileName()", "","All Files (*);;Python Files (*.py)", options=options)
        if fileName:
            print(fileName)
```

For this code, this is my output ,

fileName, _ = QFileDialog.getOpenFileName(self,"QFileDialog.getOpenFileName()", "","All Files (*);;Python Files (*.py)", options=options)
TypeError: getOpenFileName(parent: QWidget = None, caption: str = '', directory: str = '', filter: str = '', initialFilter: str = '', options: Union[QFileDialog.Options, QFileDialog.Option] = 0): argument 1 has unexpected type 'Ui_MainWindow'

How do I fix this ?

(Post Edit) :
This is my GUI code :

```
def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(443, 427)
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.pushButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.pushButton.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(350, 100, 75, 23))
        self.pushButton.setObjectName("pushButton")
        **self.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.openFileNameDialog)**
        self.lineEdit = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self.centralwidget)
        self.lineEdit.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(40, 100, 281, 21))
        self.lineEdit.setObjectName("lineEdit")
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.menubar = QtWidgets.QMenuBar(MainWindow)
        self.menubar.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 443, 21))
        self.menubar.setObjectName("menubar")
        MainWindow.setMenuBar(self.menubar)
        self.statusbar = QtWidgets.QStatusBar(MainWindow)
        self.statusbar.setObjectName("statusbar")
        MainWindow.setStatusBar(self.statusbar)

        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "MainWindow"))
        self.pushButton.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Browse"))
```

The error is thrown when I run the python script.

Comment: When exactly are you getting the error? When I run this snippet it seems to work just fine, and prints the chosen file name.

Comment: Hi , I get the error when I try to run the python script, I've edited the question and added the GUI code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks for providing the GUI code. I believe the error most likely arises from inheritance complications. I am not sure why you are passing a separate MainWindow object to various functions. Instead, try to inherit from QMainWindow() and assign all the UI elements to self.

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
from PyQt5.QtCore import *
from PyQt5.QtGui import *

class MainWindow(QMainWindow):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        self.resize(443, 427)
        self.centralwidget = QWidget(self)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.pushButton = QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.pushButton.setGeometry(QRect(350, 100, 75, 23))
        self.pushButton.setObjectName("pushButton")
        self.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.openFileNameDialog)
        self.lineEdit = QLineEdit(self.centralwidget)
        self.lineEdit.setGeometry(QRect(40, 100, 281, 21))
        self.lineEdit.setObjectName("lineEdit")
        self.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.menubar = QMenuBar(self)
        self.menubar.setGeometry(QRect(0, 0, 443, 21))
        self.menubar.setObjectName("menubar")
        self.setMenuBar(self.menubar)
        self.statusbar = QStatusBar(self)
        self.statusbar.setObjectName("statusbar")
        self.setStatusBar(self.statusbar)

        self.retranslateUi()
        QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(self)

    def retranslateUi(self):
        _translate = QCoreApplication.translate
        self.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "MainWindow"))
        self.pushButton.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Browse"))

    def openFileNameDialog(self):
        options = QFileDialog.Options()
        options |= QFileDialog.DontUseNativeDialog
        fileName, _ = QFileDialog.getOpenFileName(self,"QFileDialog.getOpenFileName()", "","All Files (*);;Python Files (*.py)", options=options)
        if fileName:
            print(fileName)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    MW = MainWindow()
    MW.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: Thanks! The seperate Main Window object was created when I converted the .ui tp .py.